# Unity) How Can I see through the canvas?

Tags: user-interface

When I do Unity, I want to make the particles pierce through the UI while leaving the canvas as an overlay. Also, Can I make it possible to see through matter? Is there any way?

Want to See through the canvas

Answer (score 0):

A canvas, by default, is completely transparent/there's nothing to render. The objects within a canvas are not necessarily transparent.

Individually you can change the alpha of the materials/images in the canvas. For something like an image, RawImage and Image, you access the alpha through the color property.

To make a whole canvas transparent consider [using a canvas group component](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1263181/how-to-change-the-alpha-of-the-whole-canvas.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Unity, when the canvas is overlayed, objects behind it cannot be seen. That's why I change the rendering type with the camera, but if you want to see it through an overlay state, how about using a shader? How about putting a shader on the UI to make it transparent?

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65991336/unity-access-sprite-secondary-texture-in-shader-for-ui-canvas-image)